# Lotus Notes 6.5: Missing "Follow Up" Toolbar Menu

Tags: lotus-notes

A user who recently migrated domino servers (from ours here in a large branch office to a random server at our home office) found she's now missing the Follow Up toolbar menu.

Normally this is seen both in the mailfile view and the message view.

Any ideas where I ought to look for it?

There are a couple questions like this on Experts Exchange, where I used to have enough points to read answers, but since I found out how smart y'all are here, I've let that lapse and the best suggestion I've found so far is to replace the mailfile design.

But I'm having trouble replacing her mailfile design. I keep getting a message telling me the database file needs to be on a domino server and not a file server to support more than one person accessing it at a time. However, I'm pretty certain the database is most certainly existing on a domino server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the design is the right course.  If you have administrative access, you should be able to replace the design directly on the server copy of the mailfile, then make sure it looks ok to you and then if necessary replace any local replicas she may have.

If you don't have access to make the change on the server directly, and have to do it from her client alone, make sure the mailfile isn't open on her welcome page or open in a crashed version of the client. It's been a while since I've done anything with 6 so I'm sure there may be specifics I'm missing.

Comment: It appears a design replace fixed it. Thanks for the answer.